# display is different in IE compared to other browserss

Tags: css

Other Browsers:
[image: Other Browser]

IE:

[image: IE]

CSS CODE:

```css
#headermenu { 
    clear: both; 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 70px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#headermenu ul { 
    padding: 0 0 0 20px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#headermenu ul li { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

In IE it's working fine but in other browser it's coming out different.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `display:inline-block` to the `li` elements, not the `ul`. I have no idea how its working in IE, except the general rule that IE does things badly and you happened to hit one that "fixed" it.

Also, I would do `list-style-type:none;` instead of `list-style:none`, and apply it to both the `ul` and `li` elements. IE vs others apply this differently, so this covers both possibilities.

Comment: Ok I updated it. Thanks.  Will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.